# Is there a port of memcache to .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, memcached

I am interested if there is a port for the server implementation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Windows Server ports:

- [memcached for Win32](http://www.splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/)
- [Jellycan Code - memcached](http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/)

Memcached .NET Client ports:

- [memcacheddotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/)
- [enyim.com Memcached Client](https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached)
- [BeIT](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/)

Comment: The first link doesn't work anymore. I think this (http://www.splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/) is the same.

Answer (score 6):

There is no official support for windows builds. Check this link: https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Install

For the clients, check this link: https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Clients

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

And you might also want to check [indeXus.net](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/) wich is implemented in c# (server and api)

We were also using BeIt as a memcached client port since we had problem with enyim.

Comment: What problems did you have with enyim?

Answer (score 1):

[Awesome port](http://www.codeplex.com/memcachedproviders) that's found on [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) :) check it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in running a memcached client on Windows then there are two additional open source servers that can do the job.  Both implement the standard memcached server protocol and are written in Java so they run on Windows.

- [jmemcached](http://code.google.com/p/jmemcache-daemon/)
- [quickcached](http://code.google.com/p/quickcached/)

Answer (score 0):

And you might want to check our [Velocity](http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/) - Microsoft's distributed cache.