# Regarding caching data in win application c#

Tags: c#, caching

Caching data in asp.net is very easy. So I just want to know how could I cache data in win application.

Suppose that I want to fetch & cache data from employee table and when ever any records will be inserted or updated in employee table then a event will fire in my form and from there I will reload those data from employee table again and cache it. It is very easy to implement in asp.net apps but how to implement this concept in win application. I don't want to use timer. please help me with concept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcache is a popular solution.  There are some .NET ports:

[Is there a port of memcache to .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276924/is-there-a-port-of-memcache-to-net)

Comment: it will be possible to reload the cache if underlying data changes with the help of memcache? please help.

Comment: This is not a good idea to use the memcached in desktop application

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh - why?  You might have a good point, but it's hard to tell without supporting information.

Comment: @Thomas - You will have to build in the logic for either notifying clients that the underlying data has changed, or you can just depend on an expiration time for each cached value.  This is the same for just about any caching provider.

Answer (score 8):

If you can target .NET 4 then you should take a look at the [`System.Runtime.Caching`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) namespace, and the [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class in particular:

> The `MemoryCache` class is similar to
>   the ASP.NET `Cache` class. The
>   `MemoryCache` class has many
>   properties and methods for accessing
>   the cache that will be familiar to you
>   if you have used the ASP.NET `Cache`
>   class. The main differences between
>   the `Cache` and `MemoryCache` classes
>   are that the `MemoryCache` class has
>   been changed to make it usable by .NET
>   Framework applications that are not
>   ASP.NET applications. For example, the
>   `MemoryCache` class has no
>   dependencies on the `System.Web`
>   assembly. Another difference is that
>   you can create multiple instances of
>   the `MemoryCache` class for use in the
>   same application and in the same
>   `AppDomain` instance.

Answer (score 2):

This would be easy if you use Microsoft application block, you may want to explore more Caching Application Block
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647280.aspx

You may want to look into specifically - [Memcached with Windows and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351635/memcached-with-windows-and-net)

Comment: I'm not going to down vote the answer, but I hate the application block code.  I've looked at it before but chose to write my own in the past.