# InMemory Database for DotNet application

Tags: .net, in-memory-database

I want to use Inmemory database for an application to be developed in DotNet. The category of Inmemory DB is (Key Value/Tuple Store) I did some googling but couldn't come to any conclusion I read about **Memcached - Key Value/Tuple Store** but since MSoft doesn't use this I was little worried.

I would request if anyone has used Inmemory in their dotnet application, please do share their experince and suggestion with the best Inmemory DB and any sample application/link  to use Inmemory database woule be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are purely C# based in memory database, such as NMemory,

http://nmemory.codeplex.com/

There are also C# wrappers that enable Memcached for C#,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96698/Implementing-Distributed-Caching-using-Memcached

http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/62

[Is there a port of memcache to .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276924/is-there-a-port-of-memcache-to-net)

Therefore, there are indeed lots of approaches available, but why couldn't you search, investigate and evaluate to find the one that best matches your scenarios? No one else can help you much, as their environment/requirements are different from yours.

Comment: Well actually I was going though a link which shows 150 inmemory DB to narrow down I have posted on this forum and I think your post is will be helpful to begin further on my R&D.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need durability or are you looking for a short term "cache" more than a long-term persistent storage? It would be interesting to get a little bit more information about what kind of information the application is supposed to store in the database. Depending on the usage of the stored information it is easier to give you an advice!

I've build two complex business applications using a database called Starcounter (www.starcounter.com). The Starcounter database is an In-memory object oriented database that supoorts true ACID transactions.

Besides the performance it has a native .NET interface where you as a developer only program the application. If a class is inherited from a base class in Starcounter it will automatically be handled as a persistent object, there is no separate database schema definition.

Starcounter is not a key-value database but rather a NewSQL database with support for SQL 92. My experience is that since it is easy to use and do not require "glue" code between the data storage and application it saves a lot of lines of code for the implementation.

Comment: Hi Niklas,Your promt response is appreciated - The requirementn I have is long-term persistent which improves performance of application by accessing the business logic rules from inmemory db  rather from disk.

Comment: Hi! Then you should consider something similar to Starcounter where you have the application and database in the same set of memory. Another feature that you might need is a query language on top of the database (SQL 92 or later) so you can easily find information in the database.